# How to setup a router to use a 10MBps dialup connection

Tags: networking, router, internet, wireless-router, pppoe

I have a broadband connection from a lesser-known ISP. Probably this is a problem with the ISP, but here it goes.

1. The ISP just gives a **Cat 5 2 pair** wire cable that comes into my home.
2. When I connect the cable to the Ehternet port of my computer, with the port's Speed set to Auto-Negotiate, the Ethernet post doesn't detect any signals at all. It says, "Cable unPlugged".
3. The moment I change the Speed of the Ethernet post to **10MBps/Full duplex**, it starts detecting the cable, and I am able to successfully dial up a connection and finally get on to the Internet.
4. It only works with the 10MBps/Full Duplex setting, and for everything else, it says "Cable unplugged".

The problem is, I want to connect a wireless roruter to be able to share the internet connection to other systems at home. But, when I connect the cable to the WAN port of the router, it doesn't detect any signal (The lights blink, but the PPPOE dial up connection never connects to the internet). So, I think the **WAN port speed is by default set to auto-negotiate**, and I can't figure out how to set it to 10MBps full duplex.

I have contacted my router's support (Netgear WNR612), but they say they can't do anything. They asked me to contact the ISP. The ISP says, that for everyone else, routers work fine. They have checked and re-checked my dial-up connection settings on the router configuration.

I suspect that if I would be able to set the speed of the WAN port of the router to 10MBps, it should start working. But given that I can't do it, or the support can't help me with this, is there anything else that I should try, before finally giving up?

I want to use my router do to the dial-up and share the internet connection.

Comment: I suspect the router doesn't like the cabling. Can you try running it to a switch, and then connecting a standard four-pair wire to your router?

Comment: Would try that today and update my findings.

Comment: That didn't work. the router still doesn't detect a signal.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I'm afraid I don't have any more suggestions. I hope you'll find a solution an post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's going to be a bit of trouble, but if this device is a Version 2 device and if you flash an older version of [OpenWRT](https://openwrt.org/toh/netgear/wnr612v2) on this device, you *might* be able to SSH into the router and run a Linux command called `ethtool` to reconfigure the WAN port for 10Mbps full duplex.  This router doesn't have a lot of memory (only 4MB of flash and 32MB of RAM) and won't run the latest version of OpenWRT, which will be a security vulnerability, so this option probably should only be tried if you're very desperate.

Note that it may not even work.  In a lot of routers, all ports are technically 1 interface and split via internal VLANs, so the chipset (AR7240) might not support changing that setting for a single physical port (it might disable auto-negotiation and set 10Mbps on all ports).

Some other things you can do:

- Ask your ISP for a recommended router
- Obtain a newer router which may have a better chipset that doesn't have this limitation.
- If your computer is a desktop, you can obtain and install a second NIC and use it as router. This will require you to setup firewalling on this computer and accept the limitations of Windows Internet Connection sharing if this is a PC.  This can be fairly complicated and involved.

Answer (score -1):

You have to setup your 2nd router as an access point and also disable DHCP and you have to give the 2nd router a static ip and finally you have to use the lan port not the wan.  The owners manual for your router has a page on how to do this 
http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/19852

Comment: But I have only one router, and I intend to use it to dial the connection for me, and not connect it as an access point.